# Etymologie du mot "désolé"

Tags: latin, étymologie

Mon intuition me suggérait avant toute recherche :

- *[quelqu'un] à qui on a retiré le **soleil***

OU

- *[quelqu'un] qui n'a plus de **sol** (sur lequel marcher/habiter/vivre)*.

---

Or, la pure intuition étant bien dangereuse seule pour ce genre de questions, quelques recherches m'ont permis de réunir des éléments de départ plus factuels.

On peut (de manière assez évidente) repérer le préfixe *dé-*, mais c'est la racine du mot qui est plus délicate. Le TLFi est [très court sur le sujet](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/d%C3%A9sol%C3%A9)¹, évoquant simplement l'équivalent latin à l'infinitif : *desolare*.

Je suis donc allé chercher du côté du verbe latin en lui-même, mais sans grands résultats je l'avoue. Le wiktionnaire annonce non pas une ni deux mais trois origines possibles pour la racine du [verbe *desolo*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/desolo#la) :

> solor (« fortifier ») ou solus, sollus (« seul », « entier »)

Et selon qu'on suit l'une, l'autre ou la troisième de ces pistes, il faut avouer que les implications symboliques/philosophiques/littéraires/poétiques n'ont strictement rien à voir.

Je serais très heureux d'en savoir plus, appel aux latinistes chevronnés !

---

¹ l'URL elle-même a l'air de vouloir s'excuser !

Comment: Ton intuition était bonne. Du latin *desolare* qui veut dire dépeupler. Alain Rey est plus explicite que le wiktionnaire.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Je cite le *dictionnaire historique de la langue française* (sld Alain Rey, ed. 1998) :

> **Désoler** est emprunté (fin XII<sup>e</sup> s.) au latin *desolare* « dépeupler, ravager » et, à basse époque, « déserter, abandonner, priver de » (surtout au participe passé), par opposition à *consolare* (→ consoler). Ce verbe est le composé intensif en *de*- de *solare* « dépeupler », proprement « laisser seul », de *solus* (→ seul).
>
> D'abord proche du mot latin, *désoler* était employé au participe passé pour « déserté » et à l'actif pour « ravager, dépeupler » (1350). Il a pris au XIV<sup>e</sup> s. sa valeur morale actuelle de « plonger dans une affliction extrême », souvent affaiblie, depuis 1672, en « contrarier, ennuyer », notamment dans l'usage poli, au participe passé (*je suis désolé*).

Comment: (+1) Merci Laure. *Désolé* partage donc sa racine avec *solitude*, et *insolation / désolation* n'ont rien en commun malgré les apparences...